# Using __builtin_popcount or other intrinsics to process the result of a _mm256_movemask_pd compare bitmap?

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, avx, bitmask

I have this piece of code and I would like to eventually implement a modified version of the  bitmask evaluation algorithm(s) from this paper - [Adapting Tree Structures for Processing with SIMD
Instructions](https://openproceedings.org/2014/conf/edbt/ZeuchFH14.pdf)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

int main(void)
{
    __m256d avx_creg, res, avx_sreg;
    int bitmask;
    uint64_t key = 503;

    avx_sreg = _mm256_castsi256_pd(_mm256_set1_epi64x(key));
    alignas(32) uint64_t v[4]; 
    _mm256_store_pd((double*)v, avx_sreg);
    printf("v2_u64: %lld %lld %lld %lld\n", v[0], v[1],v[2],v[3]);
    uint64_t b[4]= {500,505,510,515};
    avx_creg = _mm256_castsi256_pd(
                   _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i const *)&b));
    //
    alignas(32) uint64_t v1[4]; 
    _mm256_store_pd((double*)v1, avx_creg);
    printf("v2_u64: %lld %lld %lld %lld\n", v1[0], v1[1],v1[2],v1[3]);

    res      = _mm256_cmp_pd(avx_sreg, avx_creg, 30);
    bitmask  = _mm256_movemask_pd(res);
    int mmask = __builtin_popcount(bitmask);
    printf("mmask is %d\n",mmask);

    return 0;
}
```

The above  code prints the value of `mmask` as 1. So here is where I am not clear at all. Am I supposed to interpret the number "1" as the array index, where the array element is greater than the input key, or does it refer to the number of bits that are set ?

If for instance I change the key to 499 the mmask prints as 0.

Finally if I change the key to 517 the value of mmask is 4.

Can somebody clarify ? I also had a second question and I can ask this as a separate question if it is suggested. Is it possible to get all the values that are greater than the given input key from AVX intrinsics?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but plain `main()` is not a valid declaration or definition of the `main` function. See e.g. [this `main` function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) for more details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - thanks for the clarification. It does compile fine with my version of gcc i.e. 7.3 and I am a beginning C programmer ;-). So please feel free to correct.

Comment: `prog.c:8:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]` No it does not compile fine ;)

Comment: @hellow - Looks like our edits crossed :).

Comment: But are you asking about `bitmask` or `mmask`?

Comment: @harold - In this question mmask specifically.

Comment: Then it's not really a mask, it's the count of how many 1s there are in `bitmask`

Comment: @harold - l edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movemask` produces an integer bitmap by taking the high bit of each element from the vector.  Print it as hex or base-2 to see it better.

If you only care about 0 vs. non-zero counts, just check `if(bitmask != 0)`

Or `if(bitmask == 0x0f)` to check if they're all true.  (4 bits for a 4-element vector).

---

Use popcount to find out how many were true.  `__builtin_popcnt` counts the number of set bits in its input.

Use `__builtin_ctz` to find the position of the first element where the comparison was true.  (Counting from low to high memory address, if the vectors were loaded from memory).  Beware that `__builtin_ctz` is only meaningful for non-zero inputs.  e.g. in a `memchr` loop, you'd use `ctz` only after breaking out of the search loop on `_mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp_result) == 0` to establish that there was a match in this vector.  (epi8 because I'm talking about a byte-search loop, unlike your packed-`double` compares).

You might want to use BMI1 [`_lzcnt_u32(bitmask)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,SVML,Other&expand=1276,5146,5146,5048,5048,3251&text=lzcnt) to get a well-defined result (32 leading zeros) on bitmask=0, if you're already requiring AVX2.  (Because I think all AVX2 CPUs have BMI1.)

---

**To iterate over the matches**, you could use a clear-lowest-set-bit operation, and if there are still any bits set, then `ctz` to find out which one. See [Clearing the lowest set bit of a number](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/219721).

`x & (x-1)` will efficiently compile to a BMI1 `blsr` instruction if you compile with BMI1 enabled, e.g. with `-march=haswell`.

(for this to work well, you definitely want a `movemask` that matches your vector element size, so for 64-bit integer, cast your vector to `_pd` so you can use `_mm256_movemask_pd`.)

Comment: suppose I have a k-ary tree and I am at a (k-1)th node and this node has four children each of which are identified by 64 bit ints. Then I want to compare my search key with these four leaf nodes. I find that only the third leaf node is greater than the search key.  What method should I call to identify which of the leaf nodes is greater than the search key ? I am assuming the search key is one register and the leaf nodes are in another register just like the above example

Comment: @gansub: quoting from my answer: *Use `__builtin_ctz` to find the position of the first element where the comparison was true.*  Use that on the result of a `_mm256_cmpgt_epi64` / `_mm256_movemask_pd`.  It gives you an integer index.  (Or movemask epi8 and right shift the index by 3...)

Comment: One final question. Supposing both leaf node 3 *and* lead node 4 are greater than the search key. Is __builtin_ctz the method for that problem as well ? Can I "iterate" through that returned value to get all the nodes that are greater ?

Comment: @gansub: yeah, you could use a clear-lowest-set-bit operation, and if there are still any bits set, then `ctz` to find out which one.  [Clearing the lowest set bit of a number](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/219721).  (`x & (x-1)` will efficiently compile to a BMI1 `blsr` instruction if you compile with BMI1 enabled, e.g. with `-march=haswell`.)

Comment: Thanks. It is too good to leave your last comment as a "comment". I will ask that as a separate question using my tree problem as a foundation and you can presumably answer that as well.

Comment: @gansub: I edited it into the end of this answer.  You could tweak your question and still fit the answer, e.g. asking what you can do with a `movemask` result to make use of a compare result.

Comment: From your answer you write that - if(bitmask == 0x0f) to check if they are all true. What does this line of code do then - https://github.com/flippingbits/cssl/blob/master/skiplist.c#L294 ? Does it also check for all true ?

Comment: @gansub: that code is using `_ps`, so there are twice as many elements per vector, and thus twice as many set bits for all-true.